# SQL Update; Populate 1 column based on two columns (total)

Tags: sql, sum, sql-update

I need some help with one SQL statement to update one column (Total) based on two columns (Price, Quantity).  I want to update the entire table. This is simply for data analysis and not a long term solution (I would use a trigger instead).

Current Table Data

```
ID ! Price ! Quantity ! Total

1  ! 2.00  ! 2        ! NULL

2  ! 3.00  ! 1        ! NULL

3  ! 5.00  ! 2        ! NULL
```

Updated Table Data

```
Table
ID ! Price ! Quantity ! Total

1  ! 2.00  ! 2        ! 4.00

2  ! 3.00  ! 1        ! 3.00

3  ! 5.00  ! 2        ! 10.00
```

My crappy SQL obviously doesn't work

```
UPDATE Inventory
SET Total = (Price * Quantity)
```

This won't work as I need to update the entire table. I guess I would need a sub-query ??

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why didn't your `update` statement "obviously [not] work"?  What was the output?

Comment: What happens when you execute your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you posted seems fine to me.

```
UPDATE inventory SET total = (price * quantity)
```

will update the whole table row by row.

Comment: After running my query again, everything is ok. The problem is that I'm using this query while importing data in MS SQL Server SSIS. I want to populate the "Total" column while importing the data from Excel to MS SQL Server.  I get a NULL when using the same query in SSIS.